# How to find the Laplace Transform of $\sin(2t) u(t-\pi)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Using a translation theorem to determine that

$ℒ{f(t-a)u(t-a)}$ is equivalent to $F(s) e^{-as}$,

I determined that $ℒ\sin(2t)u(t-\pi)$ is equal to

$ℒ\sin(2t) * e^{-(\pi)t}$

and found the Laplace transform to be

$2/(s^2+4) * e^{-(\pi)t}$

is this correct?

Comment: You shpuld explain what $u(t)$ is.

Comment: unit step function for translation on the t axis

Comment: The Heaviside function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct, but only because $\sin(x)=\sin(x+2\pi)$.

${\cal L}(\sin(2t)u_\pi(t)) = e^{-\pi s} \cdot {\cal L}(\sin(2(t+\pi)))= e^{-pi s}\cdot{\cal L}(\sin(2t + 2\pi)) = e^{-\pi s}\cdot{\cal L}(\sin(2t)) = e^{-\pi s}\cdot {2\over s^2+4}$

Comment: what do you mean by "but only because sin(x) = sin(x + 2pi)"?

Comment: You used the wrong method but got the right answer because of luck.

Comment: so in order to use this method correctly, i must plug t - pi in to sin (2t)?

Comment: Plug $t+\pi$ into $\sin(2t)$. In general: ${\cal L}(f(t)\cdot u_c(t)) = e^{-cs} \cdot {\cal L}(f(t+c))$.